# The relationship between CoreGraphics, UIViews and CALayers

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-graphics

I always used CoreGraphics and CoreAnimation, I understand how each of them works on their own, but not those edge cases when one have to talk with the other. I also understand that `UIView`s are a nice wrapper for `CALayer`, where `CALayer` does all the heavy lifting of rendering, and the `UIView` adds the touch-based responsiveness.

But, all the questions I have seen thus far, attack the problem from one side or the other, not the interplay between them, specially between CoreGraphics and `CALayer`.

Anyway, my question is ...

## How does CoreGraphics relate to CALayer?

My understanding is that a `CALayer` wraps the CoreGraphics methods to draw itself, but does it once, and can live with the snapshot of itself until invalidated. But, how these drawing methods interplay with the sublayers of that layer? Are they exclusive?

For example, what happens when I have a `UIView` that has sub-views, and I overload the `drawRect` method? How does that affect the drawing of its sublayers?

Is it even a good idea to intermix the two inside the same function?

Also, **I'm asking only about iOS**, I understand that Mac is a different beast (and also have those fancy `CIFilters`, bastards!).

### Prior Research

Here's some related questions I've researched beforehand:

1. [confusion regarding quartz2d, core graphics, core animation, core images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9248530/confusion-regarding-quartz2d-core-graphics-core-animation-core-images). This question asks the differences between each other, and the chosen answer indeed delivers, but it answers for each individual library as if the other didn't exist.
2. [To Drawrect or not to Drawrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14659563/to-drawrect-or-not-to-drawrect-when-should-one-use-drawrect-core-graphics-vs-su?rq=1). Another great question, but it addresses only the subject of drawing CoreGraphics vs handing the problem to UIKit, but anyway, the chosen answer delivers parts of the puzzle.
3. [Animating Pie Slices with Custom CALayer](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2012/02/animating-pie-slices-using-a-custom-calayer/). Must be one of the most valuable tutorials I've seen in this subject, it's the only one that has guided me through to drawing a CALayer
4. [What is different between CoreGraphics and CoreAnimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392918/what-is-different-between-coregraphics-and-coreanimation) Absolutely disappointed on how quick the asker accepted the answer, I feel that there's a whole lot more going in here.
5. Various WWDC videos, but I haven't seen one that explains in detail the general scope. If anyone replies with a WWDC video that does, I'll consider that a valid answer.

Comment: This is such a well-stated question, I'm going to use it from now on as an example to point new users to. Well done.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I'll try to answer your question at a conceptual, 20,000ft level. I will try to disclaim my points where I'm over-generalizing, but I'll attempt to hit the common case.

Perhaps the easiest way to think about it is this: In the GPU's memory you have textures which, for the purposes of this discussion, are bitmap images. A CALayer might have a texture associated with it, or it might not. These cases would correspond to a layer with a `-drawRect:` method, and a layer that exists solely to contain sublayers, respectively. Conceptually, each layer that has a texture associated with it has a different texture all it's own (there are some details and optimizations that make this not strictly/universally true, but in the general, abstract case, it can help to think of it this way.) With that in mind, a superlayer's `-drawRect:` method has no effect on any of its sublayers' `-drawRect:` methods, and (again, in the general case) a sublayer's `-drawRect:` method has no effect on its superlayer's `-drawRect:` method. Each draws into its own texture (also called a "backing store") and then, based on the layer tree and the associated geometries and transforms, the GPU composites all these textures together into what you see on the screen. When one of the layers is invalidated, directly or indirectly (via `-setNeedsDisplayInRect:`), then when CA goes to display the next frame on screen, the invalid layers will be redrawn by virtue of having their `-drawRect:` methods called. That will update the associated texture, and once all the invalid layers' textures are updated, the GPU will composite them, generating the final bitmap that you see on-screen.

So to answer your first question: In the general case, no, there is no interplay between the `-drawRect:` methods of distinct CALayers.

As to your second question: For the purposes of this discussion you can think of UIViews as being the same as CALayers. The interrelationship with respect to drawing and textures is largely unchanged from that of non-UIView CALayers.

To your third question: Is it a good idea to intermix UIViews and CALayers? Every UIView has a CALayer backing it (all views in UIKit are layer-backed, which is not normally the case on OSX.) So at some level, they're "intermixed" whether you want them to be or not. It is perfectly fine to add CALayer sublayers to the layer that backs a UIView, although that layer will not have all the added functionality that UIView brings to the party. If that layer's purpose is just to generate an image for display, then that's fine. If you want the sub-layer/view to be a first class participant in touch handling, or to be positioned/sized using AutoLayout, then it will need to be a UIView. It's probably best to think of a UIView as a CALayer with a bunch of extra functionality added to it. If you need that functionality, use a UIView. If you don't, use a CALayer.

In sum: CoreGraphics is an API for drawing 2D graphics. One common use of CG (but not the only one) is to draw bitmap images. CoreAnimation is an API providing an organized framework for manipulating bitmaps on-screen. You could meaningfully use CoreAnimation without ever calling a CoreGraphics drawing primitive, for example, if all your textures were backed by images that were compiled into your application at build time.

Hopefully this is helpful. Leave comments if you need clarification, and I'll edit to oblige.

Comment: This is a great answer. Many people seem really confused about CoreGraphics and what it does. Many here on stackoverflow just post "use cocos2d" as some kind of weird reflex action anytime anyone asks a question about CoreGraphics or how to implement something non-trivial on iOS. CoreGraphics does the 2D rendering into bitmaps which can then be move to the graphics card via a CALayer contents property. Implemented properly, a CoreGraphics solution can be just as fast as a straight OpenGL approach because CoreGraphics and CALayer is built on top of OpenGL anyway.

Comment: A conceptual 20.000ft level answer was exactly what I was looking. I didn't need specifics, but a general sense of purpose when dealing with it. Thank you kind sir,

Comment: @ipmcc Great answer. I think I understand everything you said, but I'm still left with one question: What happens when you implement `UIView.draw(_ rect:)` *and* also   manipulate its `layer`?